# @Host() or ng-container incompatibility between angular 9 and 10

Tags: angular

Here are two live examples on stackblitz:

- [angular 9](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-0-0-ngrx-data-sample-app-tcwiw5)
- [angular 10](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-state-example-yqjgqf)

To check the difference between them, open console and notice that:

In form-error-control-name.directive.ts line 22:

For angular 9, this.parent.control is not null
For angular 10, this.parent.control will throw error

What is the difference? I checked angular 10 update doc but don't know which incompatibility this is.

Thanks!